# How can I make the pairing of the 'ltunify' program permanent?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, mouse

I have used the `ltunify` pairing tool for Logitech Unifying Receiver, [written by Lekensteyn](http://stackexchange.com/users/188676/lekensteyn), on my Logitech M510 mouse and K350 keyboard, which works perfectly. However, when I reboot, these changes are lost and I have to plug in an old keyboard so that I can re-run `ltunify`.

Is there any way to make these changes permanent so that I don't have to keep switching my devices on and off each time I reboot?

**EDIT**: After rebooting the machine and executing `ltunify list`, it shows that the devices *ARE* connected and paired, despite the fact that they are not working:

```
    Devices count: 2
    Connected devices:
    idx=1   Mouse   M510
    idx=2   Keyboard    K350
```

Note also, that:

- In the BIOS, both the keyboard and mouse work out-of-the-box
- In the GRUB boot menu, the keyboard works (cannot test the mouse, as it's not a GUI)
- In the installer (CentOS 7) both the keyboard and mouse work out-of-the-box
- CentOS 7 64-bit with kernel 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64

**EDIT2:** The system I'm using is an [Intel NUC DN2820HKFY](http://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/nuc/nuc-board-dn2820fykh.html).

Comment: That's odd, Unifying devices should stay paired across reboots without any help from software... Have you tried [Solaar](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) instead of `ltunify`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Solaar and ltunify use the same commands to trigger a pairing, it is unlikely that it would help with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned, the device have not really lost their pairing state so that should rule out hardware defects.

The most likely issue I can think of is the presence of runtime power management that somehow makes the USB port sleep and thus be unaware of the receiver. Clicking with the mouse or pressing a key should however solve such issues.

Suggestions that are worth trying:

- Plug the Logitech Unifying receiver in a different USB port. Older kernels had issues with USB 3.0 and the receiver where USB 2.0 would work. (In kernels released in the past two years, I had no such issues though.)
- Disable power management for the USB port.
- Re-insert the USB receiver when the problem occurs.

In the past, I have written this udev rules file to trigger the pairing process upon receiver insertion. Adjust the ltunify and timeout values and place them in `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-ltunify-pair.rules`.

```
# skip actual unified devices, only consider the receiver
DRIVERS=="logitech-djdevice", GOTO="do_not_pair"
# ignore devices in Linux 3.19+
DRIVERS=="logitech-hidpp", GOTO="do_not_pair"

# Skip removal, pairing makes no sense
ACTION!="add", GOTO="do_not_pair"
SUBSYSTEM!="hidraw", GOTO="do_not_pair"

# official Unifying receivers
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52b", GOTO="do_pair"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c532", GOTO="do_pair"

# "Unifying Ready" Nano receiver
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52f", GOTO="do_pair"

GOTO="do_not_pair"

LABEL="do_pair"
# 5 seconds to pair a new device
PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'sleep .5; /usr/local/bin/ltunify pair 5'"

LABEL="do_not_pair"
# vim: ft=udevrules
```

Comment: Neither clicking with the mouse or pressing a key has any effect. Neither did the three other suggestions (plugging into a different USB port, disabling USB power management or re-inserting when the problem occurs). Note, however, that this is only an issue at boot.

Comment: You still haven't provided one of the important details: the kernel version and distribution.